# How do you add multiple levels to a single transport in Winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

How does one tell Winston to log multiple levels to a single transport? For example, if you want to log both `info` and `error` level items to the console, how would you accomplish this? Specifying `info` does not log all levels that are info level and more critical, it just logs `info`. Passing an array of levels to the `level` property does nothing.

```
winston.add(winston.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true,
    level: 'info'
});
```

or

```
winston.add(winstonMongo, {
    safe: false,
    db: 'logs',
    collection: 'api',
    level: 'info'
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the log level increase incrementally? If you log debug, doesn't it include info?

Comment: There was a problem in my code preventing the logging from occurring. The 'info' level does include all more sever levels.

Comment: It looks as though there is an error in the syslog-config.js code for the levels object.  They are ordered in reverse with "emerg" at 0 and "debug" at 7.

Answer (score 10):

Specifying the `info` level does include all levels that are more severe (eg: `warn`, `error`, `debug`). Likewise, specifying `warn` includes the `warn` level, plus the more severe `error` level.

Comment: Take the following example:
logger.info('some info');
logger.error('some error');
logger.myCustomLevel('some customization');
The Console transport is added to the logger with the default level (info): I suppose that each log should be written in the console, right?
If not, how can I log different levels within a single transport?
Can you post a working example with Console, File or Whatever transport please?

Answer (score 4):

For posterity, I've included a code snippet from the winston source code detailing the default log levels. As mentioned in other answers, specifying a lower log level will log the levels above e.g. specifying `silly` will log all other levels while specifying `debug` will log all but `silly`.

```
npmConfig.levels = {
  silly: 0,
  debug: 1,
  verbose: 2,
  info: 3,
  warn: 4,
  error: 5
};
```

According to the winston [readme](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) this is the "npm" style but the npm [document](https://github.com/npm/npmlog/blob/master/log.js) it links to has different log levels.